# Continuity of a maximum with respect to parameters

Tags: real-analysis, optimization

For a function $f : \mathbb{R}^n : \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and a constant $M > 0$, we define $R : \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that:
$$
R(d) = \max_{t \in \mathbb{R}} \{ |t| : f(t d) \leq M \}
$$
Assume that the maximum is always attained for $d \neq 0$.

What conditions imply continuity of $R(d)$ on the unit circle, and why?

What conditions imply boundedness of $R(d)$ on the unit circle, and why?

Comment: Do you have any specific condition in mind? Have you tried with continuity of $f$, Lipschitz continuity of $f$, or something else?

Comment: I tried to use continuity of $f$ and prove that $R(d)$ is bounded on the unit circle. But I was not able to prove anything, and also was unable to find a counterexample. I think that some stronger conditions are required, but I don't knot what they are.

Comment: Please: what do you mean by "unit circle"? Is it the set of vecotrs having norm equal to $1$?

Comment: Yes, it indeed is.

Answer (score 0):

This is a partial answer for boundedness. Suppose $L>0$. I will denote by $B_{\rho}$ the open ball centered at $0$ of radius $\rho>0$ (inside $\Bbb R^n$), and by $S_{\rho}$ its boundary.

The following conditions are equivalent:

1. $\forall d \in S_1 \ \ \ R(d) <L$ , i.e. $R(d)$ is bounded on the unit ball by the constant $L$.
2. $\forall d \in S_1, \forall t>L \ \ \ f(td) >M$
3. $\forall t>L , \forall d \in S_t \ \ \ d \in f^{-1}(M , + \infty)$
4. $\forall t>L, S_t \subseteq f^{-1}(M , + \infty)$
5. $\bigcup_{t>L}S_t \subseteq f^{-1}(M , + \infty)$
6. $f^{-1}(0,M] \subseteq \overline{B_L}$

All steps are quite easy to be proved, simply by using definitions. Hence, your function $R(d)$ is bounded above if and only if $f^{-1}(0,M]$ is a bounded set.